# What are blocks of code in Python? The definitions are all confusing

Tags: python

I have looked up definitions, but all of them seem confusing.

<sub>Sorry I am a very new to this and I would improve it if there were a simpler way of putting it.</sub>

Comment: A block of code is a bunch of lines at the same level of indentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A code block is a *group* of statements that will be run as a *unit*.

For example:

```
if (condition):
    # Statement 1
    # Statement 2
    # Statement 3
else:
    # Statement 4
    # Statement 5
    # Statement 6
```

You will find that **statements 1,2,3** will have the same indentation and therefore is of the same block.
And similarly, **statements 4,5,6** is of a another block.

You may refer to:

*[Execution model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html)*

*[Flow of Control in Python](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3)*

Answer (score 1):

When we say "block" we mean an element of code nested inside another syntactical element, like a method or function, or a structure like `if` or `for`.

The exact definition depends on your language's syntax tree, something that's [formally defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics).

Answer (score 1):

All of your programs, consist of too many blocks.

A block is just a concept and you can't see it like as function. A block is the structure of code to separate part of the code from another part of the code.

A function is a block, and classes are blocks and self consist of many blocks inside.